# Linux command to navigate trough folder in the same directory

Tags: linux, cd

If I have the following structure:

```
directory/
 folder1/ <--
 folder2/
 folder3/
 ...
```

How to move to the next folder? Without to do:

```
cd ../folderX
```

Comment: There is no inherent notion of "next" in the file system. You can order filenames alphabetically, or by creation date, or not at all (i.e. list them in the same order as they appear in the filesystem itself). The folder itself doesn't know what its neighbours are.

Comment: Welcome to [so], a **programmer forum**. Since your question is not about programming, you probably should ask at [su] or [Unix&Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com). Given that the question is basically answered ("there is no concept of "next"), you might ask similar question on the fora mentioned in the future ,-)

Answer (score 1):

if you are using bash, you can abuse bash-arrays and use this little bash-function:

```sh
nextcd() {
    if [  $# -gt 0 ]; then
        _nextcd_dirs=("$@")
        _nextcd_root=$(pwd)
    fi
    cd "${_nextcd_root}"
    if [ -z "${_nextcd_dirs[0]}" ]; then
        echo "no more directories to change to" 1>&2
    else
        cd "${_nextcd_dirs[0]}"
        _nextcd_dirs=("${_nextcd_dirs[@]:1}")
    fi
}
```

### usage

(the beginning of each line (up to and including the `$` ) is the *prompt*, indicating where you currently are on the filesystem; the rest of the line (starting with `nextcd`) is the actual command you are running):

```sh
directory/$ nextcd folder1 folder2 folder3
directory/folder1/$ nextcd
directory/folder2/$ nextcd
directory/folder3/$ nextcd
no more directories to change to
directory/$
```

so, the first line (`nextcd folder1 folder2 folder3`) calls the function with all the directories you want to iterate through. you could use wildcards (`nextcd */`) but keep in mind that the script doesn't check whether the arguments are actual directories before trying to change to them.

it will change to the first argument immediately.

whenever you call `nextcd` (**without** any arguments), it will cd into the next of the original arguments (removing it from the list) until the list is empty (in which case it will printout an error and return to the original directory).

whenever you call `nextcd` **with** arguments, the old directories will be forgotten and you start anew.

the arguments need not be in the same directory:

```sh
nextcd /tmp ~ /usr/bin/
```

and can have duplicates:

```sh
nextcd folder1 /tmp folder1 folder2
```

#### caveats

it only works as a **function** in the current shell (so you cannot create a *script* that does this for you)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history option:

Just push the Up Arrow key to evoke a cd command with the previously visited directory at the command line. Keeping pressing the Up Arrow key until you see the previously visited directory you need and then press [Enter].

or

You might want to take advantage of the extremely handy pushd function. Pushd enables you to create a stack (a list kept in memory) of directory locations.

You can read thru this [article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/linux-directory-navigation-tips-and-tricks/) which provides further information regarding pushd function.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.